# Killbill on Google Flexible Environment using Java and Cloud SQL

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, stripe-payments, google-cloud-sql, killbill

Goal:
I want to setup subscription billing using killbill API for my client, and he is willing to use App Engine Flexible Environment where we will docker out of the box.

Confusion:
Being a developer having experience of Google App Engine I am not able to decide which way would it be more secure and better for development, killbill is saying that we can use killbill in two ways :

> (1)One could embed its webapp specific code inside Kill Bill, and therefore avoid having a separate web app. 
>   (2) Another use use case would be to embed Kill Bill into the custom web app: Below the REST API, Kill Bill offers a set of java APIs, and so it is possible to use Kill Bill as a billing library.

My Client willing is to develop api like stripe.com, is this the correct path to follow, because with google we do not have to worry about load balancing and scale ability issue?

Secondly is there any killbill jar available which I can pull using maven within my application and use it.

Please guide me so that I can provide better solution to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the easiest in your use-case would be to use the standard [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/r/killbill/killbill/) and set-up Kill Bill as a separate webapp. Regarding performance, two instances behind a load-balancer and a shared database should be enough at first. You can get more details [here](http://killbill.io/blog/performance-numbers/).

To get started, you can follow our [Getting started guide](http://docs.killbill.io/0.16/getting_started.html). We also have [documentation](https://github.com/killbill/killbill-cloud/tree/master/docker) for Docker and Docker Compose specifically.

Finally, I would suggest reaching out to our [mailing-list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/killbilling-users) for support and implementation questions.